# A Challenging Integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \arcsin(x/2) \log(x)}{x^2-1} \ dx=\frac{5 \pi^3}{1296}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I wish to evaluate the integral 
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \arcsin(x/2) \log(x)}{x^2-1} \ dx.$$ I used Mathematica's Rationalize command to see that it is equal to $5 \pi^3/1296,$ but I do not know how to prove it analytically.

**Context**

The integral appears as part of an alternative expression for the triple integral $$J=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{4-x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2y^2} \sqrt{4-x^2y^2z^2}}} \ dz \ dy \ dx.$$ It is easy to evaluate $J$ directly and show it is $\frac{\pi^3}{1296}.$  However, if we reverse the order of integration and integrate with respect to $y$ first, we get

$$J=- \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2 z^2}+\sqrt{4-x^2} z}{2 z+2}\right)}{\sqrt{4-x^2} z} \ dz \ dx.$$ The integral can be expanded into the triple integral
$$- \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z}\frac{x^2}{z \left(x^2 \left(t^2 \sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{4-t^2 x^2}\right)-4
   \left(\sqrt{4-t^2 x^2}+\sqrt{4-x^2}\right)\right)} \ dt \ dz \ dx.$$ Reversing the order of integration and integrating with respect to $x$ first, we can deduce 
\begin{align*}
J &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{t}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi }{6} t-\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\left(t-t^3\right) z} \ dz \ dt  \\
&= -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{\pi}{6} t \log(t) -\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \log(t)}{t-t^3} \ dt  \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(t)}{t^2-1} \ dt + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \log(t)}{t-t^3} \ dt \\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{48} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t \log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t^2-1} \ dt,
\end{align*}
in which we used the well-known result $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(t)}{t^2-1} \ dt = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ and partial fractions on the second integral term in the second to last equality.

Recalling $J=\pi^3/1296,$ rearranging gives
$$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{13 \pi ^3}{648} &=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t \log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t^2-1} \ dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt - I.
\end{align*}$$

**Question**

Upon using integrating by parts, it turns out 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^2(t)}{2\sqrt{4-t^2}} \ dt.$$ Further substituting $t=2 \sin(\theta)$ and using the answers in either 
[Interesting log sine integrals $\int_0^{\pi/3} \log^2 \left(2\sin \frac{x}{2} \right)dx= \frac{7\pi^3}{108}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342777/interesting-log-sine-integrals-int-0-pi-3-log2-left2-sin-fracx2-r)
or [Finding $\int^{1}_{0}\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778736/finding-int1-0-frac-ln2x-sqrt4-x2dx/2790044#2790044), we can deduce
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt = -\frac{7 \pi^3}{432}.$$ Hence, assuming this, we can get 
$$I= \frac{5 \pi^3}{1296}.$$

Can we evaluate $I$ without knowing the value of the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (t) \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{t} \ dt$ ? Can $I$ be evaluated with real methods ?

Comment: Feynman integration?

Comment: I tried that with $F(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t\arcsin(t \alpha/2) \log(t) }{t^2-1},$ but that didn't get me anywhere. Mathematica doesn't show a closed form for the antiderivative $\int \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(\frac{t\arcsin(t \alpha/2) \log(t) }{t^2-1} \right) \ dt.$

Comment: Probably of no use. I tried with $F(\alpha)=\frac{x \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \log (a x)}{x^2-1}$ and a CAS gives an answer (ugly) for $\int F'(\alpha)\,dx$ which cannot be integrated between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: An idea could be to expand the $\arcsin$ into its taylor series and evaluate the resulting integral in terms of the Gamma function and digamma function. However, this would leave you with a pretty nasty sum to simplify but you may be able to get it into a sum involving harmonic numbers that could contain a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Identities_involving_%CF%80).

Comment: @aleden In fact, I confirmed with Mathematica that $I= \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{2^{-4 n-3} \binom{2 n}{n} \psi ^{(1)}\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 n+1}.$ But indeed, it's pretty nasty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Step 1.** Substituting $x = 2\sin(\theta/2)$ and noting that

\begin{align*}
\arcsin(x/2)\log(x)
&= (\theta/2) \log(2\sin(\theta/2)) \\
&= \frac{1}{i} \log(e^{i\theta/2}) \log\bigl(i(e^{-i\theta/2} - e^{i\theta/2})\bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Im}\left[ \log^2\bigl(i(1 - e^{i\theta})\bigr) \right]
\end{align*}

for $0 < \theta < \pi$, the integral is recast as

\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin\theta}{1-2\cos\theta} \operatorname{Im}\left[ \log^2 \left( i(1 - e^{i\theta}) \right) \right] \, \mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align*}

Here, $\log(\cdot)$ is the principal logarithm. To utilize this, for $0<\epsilon<\frac{\pi}{3}$, we introduce the following auxiliary integral

$$ J_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}-\epsilon} \frac{\sin\theta}{1-2\cos\theta} \left( \log (1 - e^{i\theta}) + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta. $$

$J_{\epsilon}$ is related to $I$ by the relation $I = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\operatorname{Im}(J_{\epsilon})$.

**Step 2.** Unfortunately, $J_{\epsilon}$ diverges as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ since its real part does. The key idea in the next step is to decompose $J_{\epsilon}$ that allows to separate the diverging real part from $J_{\epsilon}$.

Consider the curve $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ which is defined by $\gamma_{\varepsilon}(\theta) = 1 - e^{i\theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}-\epsilon$, and substitute $z = \gamma_{\varepsilon}(\theta)$. Then

\begin{align*}
J_{\epsilon}
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{\frac{1}{2i}\bigl((1-z) - \frac{1}{1-z}\bigr)}{1-\bigl((1-z) + \frac{1}{1-z}\bigr)} \left(\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{i(z-1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}} \left( \frac{3z^2}{z^3+1} - \frac{2z}{z^2-1} \right) \left(\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= A_{\epsilon} - B_{\epsilon},
\end{align*}

where $A_{\epsilon}$ and $B_{\epsilon}$ are defined by

$$ A_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}} \frac{3z^2}{z^3+1} \left(\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z
\quad\text{and}\quad
B_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}} \frac{2z}{z^2-1} \left(\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z. $$

To further simplify these integrals, we observe that

$$ \log z = \frac{1}{2}\log(z^2) = \frac{1}{3}\log (-z^3) - \frac{i\pi}{3} \qquad \text{for } z \in \gamma_{\epsilon}. $$

Here, the last step is a consequence of the branch cut of $\log(\cdot)$ together with the fact that the contours corresponding to $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$, $\gamma_{\varepsilon}^2$, and $-\gamma_{\varepsilon}^3$ are as follows:

[image: contours of gamma powers]

So, by applying further substitutions $-z^3 \mapsto z$ and $z^2 \mapsto z$ to $A_{\epsilon}$ and $B_{\epsilon}$, respectively, we get

\begin{align*}
A_{\epsilon} &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\gamma_{\epsilon}^3} \frac{1}{z-1} \left( \frac{1}{3}\log z + \frac{i\pi}{6} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z, \\
B_{\epsilon} &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}^2} \frac{1}{z-1} \left( \frac{1}{2}\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z.
\end{align*}

**Step 3.** For $A_{\varepsilon}$, the integrand has a simple pole at $z = 1$. Moreover, the terminal point of $-\gamma_{\epsilon}^3$ has an asymptotic formula of the form

$$ -(1-e^{i(\pi/3 - \epsilon)})^3
= 1 - 3e^{i\pi/6}\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\qquad \text{as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.} $$

[image: contour of negative gamma cube]

So by replacing $-\gamma_{\epsilon}^3$ by the union of

- $z = x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1-3\epsilon$, which is the line segment from $0$ to $1-3\epsilon$;
- $z = 1 - 3\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$, which is the circular arc from $1-3\epsilon$ to $1-3\epsilon e^{i\pi/6}$;
- the line segment from $1-3\epsilon e^{i\pi/6}$ to the terminal point of $-\gamma_{\epsilon}^3$;

it follows that

\begin{align*}
&A_{\epsilon} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1-3\epsilon} \frac{1}{x-1} \left( \frac{1}{3}\log x + \frac{i\pi}{6} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
 + \frac{i}{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \left( \frac{1}{3}\log(1 - 3\epsilon e^{i\varphi}) + \frac{i\pi}{6} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\varphi
 + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon) \\
&= \frac{i\pi}{36} \int_{0}^{1-3\epsilon} \frac{\log x}{x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x
+ \frac{i}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi}{6} \left( \frac{i\pi}{6} \right)^2
+ \text{[some real number]}
+ \mathcal{O}(\epsilon).
\end{align*}

As $\epsilon \to 0^+$, its imaginary part converges to

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Im} (A_{\epsilon})
= \frac{\pi}{36} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x}{x-1} \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{\pi^3}{864}
= \frac{\pi^3}{288}.
$$

**Step 4.** For $B_{\epsilon}$, its limit is simply $B_0$. So,

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} B_{\epsilon}
= B_0
= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{e^{-2\pi i/3}} \frac{1}{z-1} \left( \frac{1}{2}\log z + \frac{i\pi}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z $$

Performing integration by parts twice, we end up with

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} B_{\epsilon}
= -\frac{\pi^2}{144}\log\bigl(1 - e^{-2\pi i/3} \bigr) + \frac{i\pi}{24} \operatorname{Li}_2\bigl( e^{-2\pi i/3} \bigr) - \frac{1}{8} \operatorname{Li}_3\bigl( e^{-2\pi i/3} \bigr)$$

Although the exact value of $\operatorname{Li}_2\left( e^{-2\pi i/3} \right)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_3\left( e^{-2\pi i/3} \right)$ are not known, it only suffices to know the values of $\operatorname{Re}\left[ \operatorname{Li}_2\left( e^{-2\pi i/3} \right) \right]$ and $\operatorname{Im}\left[ \operatorname{Li}_3\left( e^{-2\pi i/3} \right) \right]$. Moreover, these values can be computed using the [Fourier series of the Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series). The upshot of this observation is that

$$ \operatorname{Re}\bigl[ \operatorname{Li}_2\bigl( e^{-2\pi i/3} \bigr) \bigr] = -\frac{\pi^2}{18}, \qquad
\operatorname{Im}\bigl[ \operatorname{Li}_3\bigl( e^{-2\pi i/3} \bigr) \bigr] = -\frac{2\pi^3}{81}. $$

Putting altogether, we end up with

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Im}( B_{\epsilon} ) = -\frac{\pi^3}{2592}, $$

**Conclusion.** Combining all the efforts and using the relation

$$ I
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Im}(J_{\epsilon})
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \operatorname{Im}(A_{\epsilon} - B_{\epsilon}), $$

the desired equality is proved.

Comment: Nice solution. Do you suspect there might be a solution involving real variables ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik, I guess so, but at least I have no good hint for that direction.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for real methods?

Comment: @clathratus, That is OP's second question. My interpretation was that OP was primarily interested in any form of solution, but would prefer real methods. I will gladly let OP change his/her mind if anyone comes up with better solution with real method.